# How to group the data based on server and get the latest data

Tags: javascript, typescript

here's the code:

```
rowData = [
{
            server: "Server 1",
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },{
            server: "Server 1",
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:40:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:45:000"
        },{
            server: "Server 1",
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:15:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:25:000"
        },{
            server: "Server 1",
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:10:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:15:000"
        },{
            server: "Server 1",
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:05:000"
        },{
            server: "Server 1",
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 07:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:05:000"
        },{
            server: "Server 1",
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 06:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 07:05:000"
        },{
            server: "Server 1",
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 05:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 06:05:000"
        },{
            server: "Server 1",
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 04:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 05:05:000"
        }

{
            server: "Server 2",
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:03:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
            },
            {
            server: "Server 2",
            ping: "2 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:01:000"
            }
}
```

What I want to do is group the data based on the server which is the "Server 1" and then it will get the latest data. it depends if it will be based on the date which is the `dateStart` and `dateEnd`.

output should be like this:

```
[
    {
        server: "Server 1",
        ping: "10 ms",
        dl: "50Mbit/s",
        ul: "50Mbit/s",
        ispcon: true,
        dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
        dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        data: [
        {
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },{
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:40:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:45:000"
        },{
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:15:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:25:000"
        },{
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:10:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:15:000"
        },{
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:05:000"
        },{
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 07:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:05:000"
        },{
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 06:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 07:05:000"
        },{
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 05:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 06:05:000"
        },{
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 04:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 05:05:000"
        }
        ]
        },
        {
        server: "Server 2",
        ping: "10 ms",
        dl: "50Mbit/s",
        ul: "50Mbit/s",
        ispcon: true,
        dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:03:00",
        dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        data: [
        {
            ping: "10 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:03:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
            },
            {
            ping: "2 ms",
            dl: "50Mbit/s",
            ul: "50Mbit/s",
            ispcon: true,
            dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
            dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:01:000"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: Why are you repeating all of the properties of the first object in each server array? Why not just have server and data as the top-level properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: @symlink because sir, I will apply it in master detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `reduce` method and combine with `Object.values`. Below is sample code in one line.

```js
const rowData = [
  {
    server: "Server 1",
    ping: "10 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  },
  {
    server: "Server 1",
    ping: "10 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:40:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:45:000"
  },
  {
    server: "Server 1",
    ping: "10 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:15:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:25:000"
  },
  {
    server: "Server 1",
    ping: "10 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:10:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:15:000"
  },
  {
    server: "Server 1",
    ping: "10 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 08:00:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:05:000"
  },
  {
    server: "Server 1",
    ping: "10 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 07:00:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 08:05:000"
  },
  {
    server: "Server 1",
    ping: "10 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 06:00:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 07:05:000"
  },
  {
    server: "Server 1",
    ping: "10 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 05:00:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 06:05:000"
  },
  {
    server: "Server 1",
    ping: "10 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 04:00:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 05:05:000"
  },

  {
    server: "Server 2",
    ping: "10 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:03:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  },
  {
    server: "Server 2",
    ping: "2 ms",
    dl: "50Mbit/s",
    ul: "50Mbit/s",
    ispcon: true,
    dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
    dateEnd: "2019-10-12 09:01:000"
  }
];

const res = Object.values(
  rowData.sort((a, b) => 
     (new Date(a.dateStart).getTime()) - 
       (new Date(b.dateStart).getTime())).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { server, ...rest_curr } = curr;
    return {
      ...acc,
      [curr.server]:
        curr.server in acc
          ? {
              ...acc[curr.server],
              data: [...acc[curr.server].data, { ...rest_curr }]
            }
          : { ...curr, data: [{ ...rest_curr }] }
    };
  }, {})
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: How to remove the server inside the parent

Comment: @ABC, Just updated the answer. Basically go thru items after process and remove the property. (Alternatively you can also use `Reflect.deleteProperty` in map method).

Comment: Sir siva not the parent server. the child property. ```{server: "Server 1", ...etc., data: [ { ping, dl, ul, ispcon, dateStart, dateEnd}]}```

Comment: ```Property 'server' does not exist on type '{}'``` there's an error

Comment: Sorry @ABC, my bad, Now updated the answer to remove the `server` from data array. Check this.

Comment: How to Sort the data based on the date

Comment: @ABC, Sample sort can do is like `rowData.sort((a, b) => 
     (new Date(a.dateStart).getTime()) - 
       (new Date(b.dateStart).getTime()))`, This will be sort based on dateStart. Updated the answer. Please change it accordingly to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash for your use case, you can simply do

```
let serverData = _.groupBy(rawData, dataObj => dataObj.server)
```

Where `serverData` would be the result you are looking for, `rawData` will be your initial data and `dataObj` will be the individual object inside the `rawData`.

You can also follow [this link](https://dustinpfister.github.io/2018/08/02/lodash_groupby/) for more details on `groupBy` method.
Here is the [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) in lodash for the above method.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your returned object a bit, so the top level properties are just `server` and `data`, and `server` is removed from the second level objects.

```js
let arr=rowData=[{server:"Server 1",ping:"10 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 09:00:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 09:05:000"},{server:"Server 1",ping:"10 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 08:40:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 08:45:000"},{server:"Server 1",ping:"10 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 08:15:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 08:25:000"},{server:"Server 1",ping:"10 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 08:10:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 08:15:000"},{server:"Server 1",ping:"10 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 08:00:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 08:05:000"},{server:"Server 1",ping:"10 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 07:00:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 08:05:000"},{server:"Server 1",ping:"10 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 06:00:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 07:05:000"},{server:"Server 1",ping:"10 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 05:00:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 06:05:000"},{server:"Server 1",ping:"10 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 04:00:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 05:05:000"},{server:"Server 2",ping:"10 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 09:03:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 09:05:000"},{server:"Server 2",ping:"2 ms",dl:"50Mbit/s",ul:"50Mbit/s",ispcon:!0,dateStart:"2019-10-12 09:00:00",dateEnd:"2019-10-12 09:01:000"}];

let res = rowData.reduce((acc,cur) => {
    if(acc.some(el => el.server && el.server === cur.server)){
        return acc.map(el => {
            if(el.server === cur.server){
                delete cur.server
                el.data.push(cur) 
            }            
            return el
        })
    }else{
        let server = cur.server
        delete cur.server
        return acc.concat({server: server, data: [cur]})
    }
    
},[])

console.log(res)
```