# How can I transform an array of objects into a new array of objects grouped by property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Please see my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/so4u0j8y/) which includes all the code that follows.

My apologies if this question has been answered before. I found similar questions on here about grouping by property, but I did not find an example where the result was still an array of objects.

I'm starting with this data format:

```js
const originalData = [
  {
    "groupId": 0,
    "color": "red",
    "shape": "circle"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "color": "green",
    "shape": "square"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "color": "orange",
    "shape": "hexagon"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "color": "purple",
    "shape": "triangle"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 2,
    "color": "aqua",
    "shape": "diamond"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 2,
    "color": "blue",
    "shape": "trapezoid"
  }
];
```

And I would like to transform it into a new array of objects, grouped by `groupId` property value:

```js
const desiredData = [
  {
    "groupId": 0,
    "items": [
      {
        "color": "red",
        "shape": "circle"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        "color": "green",
        "shape": "square"
      },
      {
        "color": "orange",
        "shape": "hexagon"
      },
      {
        "color": "purple",
        "shape": "triangle"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupId": 2,
    "items": [
      {
        "color": "aqua",
        "shape": "diamond"
      },
      {
        "color": "blue",
        "shape": "trapezoid"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This reduce function (which I found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Grouping_objects_by_a_property)) is the closest I was able to come to transforming my data. My experience with transforming data in Javascript is limited, and I am not sure how to add fields (like `group`) during the transformation process. Also, the result is an object, not an array of objects.

```js
const actualFormattedData = originalData.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  let key = obj['groupId'];
  if (!acc[key]) {
    acc[key] = [];
  }
  acc[key].push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Output from the reduce function:

```json
{
  "0": [
    {
      "groupId": 0,
      "color": "red",
      "shape": "circle"
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "groupId": 1,
      "color": "green",
      "shape": "square"
    },
    {
      "groupId": 1,
      "color": "orange",
      "shape": "hexagon"
    },
    {
      "groupId": 1,
      "color": "purple",
      "shape": "triangle"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "groupId": 2,
      "color": "aqua",
      "shape": "diamond"
    },
    {
      "groupId": 2,
      "color": "blue",
      "shape": "trapezoid"
    }
  ]
}
```

The ultimate goal is to map the array of objects in React. I know I can use `Object.entries` and array indices to achieve a similar result with `actualFormattedData` as-is, but it would be ideal if I could first make `actualFormattedData` look exactly like `desiredData`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const dict = originalData.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  let groupId = obj['groupId'];
  delete obj.groupId;
  if (!acc[groupId]) {
    acc[groupId] = { // here is where we add the fields you wanted
        groupId,
        items: []
      };
  }
  acc[groupId].items.push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});

// turn this into an array, just getting the values of the fields in the dictionary
const actualFormattedData = Object.values(dict);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had to make a tweak to your function on line 4 (`acc[key]` -> `acc[groupId]`). Result is this which is what I was looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/u1fsngto/

Comment: With this function, is it also possible to remove fields? I noticed that `groupId` is still present in the item objects, that's more of a nice-to-have. I can live with it being in both places I think, especially if would add a performance hit to try to remove fields while it's iterating.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I like that it only iterates through the array once. I also like that I don't have to explicitly set each field. Seems to be the most efficient and straightforward. As mentioned, it would be nice to be able to omit the `groupId` field inside of each item object, since it's redundant at that point, but whether or not that feature would be performant and/or easy to add, I still think this is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to remove the `groupId` field. I've added the necessary line (`delete obj.groupId`).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be achieved with a single call to [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), as detailed in the code snippet below.

Just a note that this solution emphasises simplicity over efficiency, and would tend to not be suitable for very large input arrays:

```js
const originalData=[{groupId:0,color:"red",shape:"circle"},{groupId:1,color:"green",shape:"square"},{groupId:1,color:"orange",shape:"hexagon"},{groupId:1,color:"purple",shape:"triangle"},{groupId:2,color:"aqua",shape:"diamond"},{groupId:2,color:"blue",shape:"trapezoid"}];

/* Use reduce to iterate and transform originalData array to desired result */
const desiredData = originalData.reduce((result, item) => {
  
  /* The group item to add from this iteration */
  const groupItem = { color : item.color, shape : item.shape };
  
  /* Search for item that already exists with matching group id */
  const existingGroup = result.find(resultItem => resultItem.groupId === item.groupId);
  if(existingGroup) {
    /* Add item to group if found */
    existingGroup.items.push(groupItem);
  }
  else {
    /* Add group with item if not group found */
    result.push({ 
      groupId : item.groupId,
      items : [ groupItem ]
    });
  }
  
  return result;
  
}, []);

console.log(desiredData);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This should work but is not very efficient, since you will do a scan of the array in each iteration, O(n^2), when this can be done in O(n) by using an object (which has O(1) access by field name).

Comment: That's correct - I should preface this answer with a note that it emphasises simplicity over efficiency. If the data set were larger, an alternate solution would be a better fit.

Comment: Dacre, thanks for taking the time to answer my question. As Christian pointed out, performance might be a concern for the practical application of this function, as I don't know exactly how large the array might get. But this solution does indeed transform the data exactly as I had requested!

Comment: You're more than welcome - at the very least, this might help to show other ways `reduce()` can be used! All the best with your project :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fiddle solution

https://jsfiddle.net/07n9ks86/

and the crucial code for it (n2):

```
const formattedData = originalData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  console.log(acc)
  const index = acc.findIndex(x => x.group === curr.group);
  if (index > 0) {
    acc[index] = {
      ...acc[index],
      items: [...acc[index].items,
        {
          'color': curr.color,
          'shape': curr.shape
        }
      ]
    }
  } else {
    acc.push({
      group: curr.group,
      items: [{
        'color': curr.color,
        'shape': curr.shape
      }]
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Eugen, thanks for taking the time to provide this answer! I ended up going with Christian's solution because it only iterates through the data once (I'm assuming this `findIndex` is also looping through the array inside of the reduce function), but this is an interesting approach that I would not have thought of. Also I appreciate that you provided an updated fiddle in your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy to understand solution:

```js
const originalData = [
  {
    "groupId": 0,
    "color": "red",
    "shape": "circle"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "color": "green",
    "shape": "square"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "color": "orange",
    "shape": "hexagon"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "color": "purple",
    "shape": "triangle"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 2,
    "color": "aqua",
    "shape": "diamond"
  },
  {
    "groupId": 2,
    "color": "blue",
    "shape": "trapezoid"
  }
];
const data = [];
const dataObjIndex = id=>{
  for(let i=0,l=data.length; i<l; i++){
    if(data[i].groupId === id){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
originalData.forEach(o=>{
  let i = dataObjIndex(o.groupId);
  if(i === -1){
    i = data.length; data.push({groupId:o.groupId, items:[]});
  }
  data[i].items.push({color:o.color, shape:o.shape});
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, StackSlave. As I mentioned above, I ended up going with Christian's answer because it was only iterating through the data once.

Answer (score 0):

Another simplest method to group by property name can be using lodash.

```
let groupedData = _.groupBy(rawData, dataObj => dataObj.propertyToGroupBy)
```

Where `groupedData` is the result you are looking for, `rawData` is the original data and `propertyToGroupBy` is the property of the object with which you want to group.

You can check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727626/how-to-group-the-data-based-on-server-and-get-the-latest-data/59727736#59727736)